# How to extract the date from string and aggregate it?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which has two features **item_listing_time**  and **item_sale_time**.

Those are strings and looks like this:

| item_listing_time | item_sale_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-09-30T19:06:21.000-07:00 | 2018-09-30T23:06:21.000-07:00 |

I want to create a feature **sold_in_24h** which is True when sale happens in 24h.

At the moment my workflow looks like this:

```
# replacing "T" and "." char in item_listing_time and item_sale_time columns by space
data2['item_listing_time'] = data2['item_listing_time'].str.replace('T',' ')
data2['item_listing_time'] = data2['item_listing_time'].str.replace('.',' ')
data2['item_sale_time'] = data2['item_sale_time'].str.replace('T',' ')
data2['item_sale_time'] = data2['item_sale_time'].str.replace('.',' ')

# storing datetime into datetime_listing column as datetime type
data2['date_listing'] = data2.litem_listing_time.str.split(' ').str[0]
data2['time_listing'] = data2.item_listing_time.str.split(' ').str[1]
data2['datetime_listing'] = data2.date_listing + " "+data2.time_listing

data2['datetime_listing'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['datetime_listing'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


# same with saletime
data2['date_sale'] = data2.item_sale_time.str.split(' ').str[0]
data2['time_sale'] = data2.item_sale_time.str.split(' ').str[1]
data2['saletime'] = data2.date_sale + " "+data2.time_sale

data2['saletime'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['saletime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


# creating column for sold_in_24h
data2["was_sold_in_24h"] = (data2["saletime"] - data2["datetime_listing"]) < pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

This method works, but not sure is it neat way to solve this problem.

Any opinions how to improve it or leave it this way, as it provides the desired result.

Thanks!

Comment: One option is that you can **chain them together** for single case, it will be little better in terms of efficiency, like this: `data2['item_sale_time'] = data2['item_sale_time'].str.replace('.',' ').replace('T',' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert directly the `"item_listing_time"` and `"item_sale_time"` to datetime:

```
df["item_listing_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["item_listing_time"])
df["item_sale_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["item_sale_time"])

one_day = pd.Timedelta(days=1)
df["sold_in_24h"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["item_listing_time"] + one_day > x["item_sale_time"], axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          item_listing_time            item_sale_time  sold_in_24h
0 2018-09-30 19:06:21-07:00 2018-09-30 23:06:21-07:00         True
```

Comment: I just replaced lambda function with:

data2["sold_in_24h"] = (data2["saletime"] - data2["datetime_listing"]) < pd.Timedelta(days=1)

Seemed more efficient way

Answer (score 0):

**For replacing "T" and "." char in item_listing_time and item_sale_time columns by space:**

One option you can use is that, `replace` calls can be **chained together** for single case, it will be better like this:

```
data2['item_sale_time'] = data2['item_sale_time'].str.replace('.',' ').replace('T',' ')
```

**For storing datetime into datetime_listing column as datetime type:**

Store the `split` result and use it:

```
data = data2.litem_listing_time.str.split(' ')
data2['date_listing'] = data[0]
data2['time_listing'] = data[1]
```

But these are very basic tip-offs, I will also be looking for some deep-thought suggestions here!